# Get List Of More From Developer To Mobile App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-api, google-developers-console

I want to list all my applications of my developer account.
I can get that in web with following link : 
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id={my developer id} 
 But as it can't be accessed in mobile application, so is there any api key or anything i can use to achieve? 
 Any help would be great. 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this create one webview and load your desired URL in that webview.

Here is the webview code. https://www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/

Comment: Thank you for that link.
But i want it to be like i can list all my apps within one app so user can view and redirected to app if button is clicked, but not in webview.